# Aurelia binding returning null on custom element

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to pass a collection of data to a custom element using Aurelia but am getting null when trying to access the data in the custom element.  I have included a gist of my issue:  https://gist.run/?id=3c51fff719dc4b482136dadb860618fd

Comment: while this doesn't solve the problem you've got `seriesDefault` in your `chartExample.html` and `seriesDefaults` in your `chartExample.js`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just half an answer as there's still an error, but updating `chartExample.js` as per below at least gives you a chart

```
import {inject, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework'; 

export class ChartExample{
  @bindable info

  infoChanged(value){
    this.seriesDefaults = this.info.seriesDefaults;
    this.series = this.info.series;
    this.valueAxis = this.info.valueAxis;
    this.categoryAxis = this.info.categoryAxis;
    this.tooltip = this.info.tooltip;    
  }
}
```

**Edit**: I guess your JSON wasn't valid too as it works now...

```
{
    "title": "CHART",
    "seriesDefaults": {
        "type": "area",
        "area": {
            "line": {
                "style": "smooth"
            }
        }
    },

    "series": [{
        "name": "India",
        "data": [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855]
    }, {
        "name": "World",
        "data": [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
    }, {
        "name": "Haiti",
        "data": [-0.253, 0.362, -3.519, 1.799, 2.252, 3.343, 0.843, 2.877, -5.416, 5.590]
    }],

    "valueAxis": {
        "labels": {
            "format": "{0}%"
        },
        "line": {
            "visible": false
        },
        "axisCrossingValue": -10
    },

    "categoryAxis": {
        "categories": [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011],
        "majorGridLines": {
            "visible": false
        },
        "labels": {
            "rotation": "auto"
        }
    },

    "tooltip": {
        "visible": true,
        "format": "{0}%",
        "template": "${series.name} ${value}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import {inject, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';
import {Service} from './service';

@inject(HttpClient, Service)
export class App {

  //@bindable chart;

  constructor(httpClient, service){
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
    this.service = service;
  }

  activate() {
    return this.service.getAllCharts()
      .then(chart => {
         this.chart = chart;
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't want the return in the activate because I have other things to run in activate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: in `app.js`, `chart` is not initialized until `service.getAllCharts()` finish. At that time, the custom element is already attached (i.e its `bind()` already run).

Logically, you want to attach the custom element only after the necessary data already initialized. You can modify `app.html` like below:

```
<chart-example if.bind="chart" info.bind="chart"></chart-example>
```

This way, you can make `<chart-example>` response "one-time" to the input data.

Another way is to make `<chart-example>` itself observe the bindable property `info` and act accordingly. This way, you can make the custom element continuously response to input data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to but the chart calls into the bind(){} function on the chartExample.js

```
import {inject, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework'; 

export class ChartExample{
  @bindable info

  bind(){
    this.seriesDefaults = this.info.seriesDefaults;
    this.series = this.info.series;
    this.valueAxis = this.info.valueAxis;
    this.categoryAxis = this.info.categoryAxis;
    this.tooltip = this.info.tooltip;    
  }
}
```